# Определить тип хеша

Tags: php

Добрый день. Интересует следующий вопрос: Можно ли с помощью php, осуществить проверку строки на наличие зашифрованного текста в DES (Linux)?

Время от времени спасала данная регулярка

```
 (?=.*([a-z].*?[a-z]))(?=.*([A-Z].*?[A-Z]))
```

но сейчас есть необходимость ее убрать, на более надёжное...

Вот пример строк: SUmUgiFUMmo, vWH4hvuJnru7

Comment: Как связан DES, хэш, и алфавит A-Z?

Comment: Поправил первый пост.

Comment: Приведенные строки практически наверняка НЕ являются результатом обычного применения шифрования, потому что в результате шифрования распределение байтов должно быть более равномерным и, следовательно, не содержащим информации о примененном алгоритме.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов существуют различные подходы к хешированию. В частности, многие из них рекомендуют добавлять в начало хеша соль и метаинформацию, например. Имея соль и зная общую длину хеша можно даже вычислить алгоритм, которым было произведено хеширование.

Comment: @rjhdby какая связь между DES и хэшированием? Какой алгоритм хэширования использовался тут: a2f6e9bcd1667082da7bab28d04bbf19?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.passwords.php

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов скорее всего SHA-256, если это действительно хеш, а не случайный набор символов. Впрочем может быть и любой другой алгоритм, возвращающий строку в 256 бит, но автору то нужно определить сам факт :) Опять таки, я не зря говорил про разные подходы. Стандартные функции хеширования пароля в PHP вставляют в начало четкие маркеры алгоритма

Comment: @rjhdby Верно замечено, что хэш не отличить от случайных байт, о чем и речь. Маркеров в примере нет, зато наверняка есть Base64, под которым маркеров тоже нет.